# Text not showing up in flex-row

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

My outer div has `d-flex flex-row` and I have three sub divs total. Two of them are `btn-group` and the other one is a div with text. I have all this in another div that I have class `center-block`. To get these sub divs to show, I have made them `z-index: 1`. The buttons are showing up but not the text.

```
    <div class="center-block">
       <div class="d-flex flex-row">
           <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="..." style="z-index: 1;">
            <!-- Two buttons here -->
       <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="..." style="z-index: 1;">
            <!-- One button here -->
        <div aria-label="..." style= "z-index:1">Hello</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I can't really add my code here because I'm not allowed to. If you could give me a simple example that would be fine. I think I'm just missing the logic here. I just need three things on the flex-row. The three buttons in the left side of the row and the text centered with in that row.

Answer (score 0):

Since Bootstrap 4 beta3, `.center-block` has been dropped, in favor of `.mx-auto`: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/migration/#utilities. But since you haven't mentioned what you expect with putting `.center-block` on everything, I didn't include that in my fiddle.

The text is showing up without the help of `z-index`.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/104420/

Comment: Thanks for putting this together. However, this is not really what I'm looking for. I will look into mx-auto which I have not researched yet.

Comment: Then tell us what you are looking for and expectation with the help of '.center-block'